# How to prove using probability distribution rules that $P(Y_1,Y_2,X_3)*P(Y_3|X_3) = P(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,X_3)$

Tags: probability-distributions, chain-rule

How to prove using probability distribution rules that $P(Y_1,Y_2,X_3)*P(Y_3|X_3) = P(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,X_3)$

I am not considering any other assumptions for this question.
Even if I consider expanding $P(Y_1,Y_2,X_3)*P(Y_3|X_3)$ to $\frac{P(Y_1,Y_2,X_3)*P(Y_3,X_3)}{P(X_3)}$, I am stuck with the denominator $P(X_3)$

Currently stuck at trying to show that $\frac{P(Y_1,Y_2,X_3)*P(Y_3,X_3)}{P(X_3)} = P(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,X_3)$

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ? [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [How to ask a good question ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Currently stuck at trying to show that $\frac{P(Y1,Y2,X3)*P(Y3,X3)}{P(X3)} = P(Y1,Y2,Y3,X3)$

Answer (score 0):

Well, the factorisation $\mathsf P(Y_1,Y_2,X_3)\,\mathsf P(Y_3\mid X_3)=\mathsf P(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,X_3)$, is *not generally* true.

However, consider that because, $\mathsf P(Y_1, Y_2, X_3) = \mathsf P(Y_1, Y_2\mid X_3)\,\mathsf P(X_3)$, you could prove your factorisation *if* $Y_1\cap Y_2$ and $Y_3$ were *conditionally independent* given $X_3$.

Are they?